# Access 2013 - Custom Web App - "Access denied" error when creating

Tags: database, ms-access, sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a custom web app in Access 2013.

In the "Web Location" field I'm entering the url to a Sharepoint 2013 site to which i have "full control" access.

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I've enabled the "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" under site settings and site collection settings. (*Description of the feature:* Features such as InfoPath Forms Services, Visio Services, Access Services, and Excel Services Application, included in the SharePoint Server Enterprise License.)

What am i missing? Why the access denied error?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I created a blank web database on Access 2010 and published to sharepoint. It went through and was deployed. Then opened the same database in Access 2013 from sharepoint and was able to work on it and re-deploy without any problems.